# What is Query Offloading

Tags: database, oracle, query-optimization

I was reading about Oracle Golden Gate 11g and came accross the term

"Query Offloading"

After googling also I couldn't find the exact answer for it.
Although I understood in someway it is related to query optimization.

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Query offloading" refers to an architecture where you create a near real-time reporting database that is separate from the production OLTP database and then use that replica to run your reporting queries rather than running them directly against the production database.  That ensures that reporting queries do not negatively affect your production OLTP activity.  And, depending on how you create the reporting database, it may make it easier to optimize your reporting queries by doing things like creating additional indexes that are useful for reports without forcing your OLTP processes to incur the overhead of maintaining those indexes.

Answer (score 1):

[ask tom](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-nov/o69asktom-089919.html) mentioned what is  standby query offloading, hope it can help you.